# How to reset firbaseui in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

**Problem:** Once I try to re-render the firebaseUI after hiding it, it won't reappear and cannot find a way to clear the `AuthUI`

**Background**:
I have a React component that shows the firebaseUI login screen and I track the login by passing a prop from the  to the child  component. This prop conditionally determines what JSX to render. Now I can successfully render the firebaseUI, then login, and then sign out. But that's where it breaks. Upon signout, the component re-renders the `<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>` and the disclaimer `<p>` but I only ever see the `<p>` and not the login again.

**What I tried:** So I cannot just rerun the code to re display it because `var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());` will cause an error saying this AuthUI already exists. So I need to use their `reset()` function first before being able to rerun the code but I can never get it to work because I get an error similar to `ui.reset() is undefined`...

**CODE**

**login.js component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {fire, initApp} from '../fire';
import '../../node_modules/firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css';

var firebase = require('firebase');
var firebaseui = require('firebaseui');


class Login extends Component {   
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state={};
    }

componentDidMount(){    
    this.showFirebaseUILogin();
}

showFirebaseUILogin(){
    // FirebaseUI config.
    var uiConfig = {
        callbacks:{
            signInSuccess: (currentUser, credential) => {
                //save to state
                this.props.savetoState('login',true,currentUser,credential);
                return;
            }
        },
        signInSuccessUrl:'/',
        signInOptions: [
            // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
            firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            // firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            // firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            // firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            // firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
        ],
        // Terms of service url.
        tosUrl: '',
    };

    // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
    var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
    initApp();
    // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
    console.log('Initializing login');
}

render(){
    if(this.props.show){
        return(
            <div>
                {/* <div id="sign-in-status"></div> */}
                {/* <div id="sign-in"></div> */}
                {/* <div id="account-details"></div> */}
                <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
                <p className="disclaimer" style={{fontSize:'14px',color:'grey',maxWidth:'90vw',margin:'8px auto'}}><span style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>Disclaimer: </span>
                    Phone numbers that end users provide for authentication will be sent to and stored by Google to improve their spam and abuse prevention across Google services, including but not limited to Firebase. By signing in, the user is agreeing to these terms.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    else{
        return(
            <div>
                <button className="signOutBtn" onClick={this.props.logout}>Sign Out</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize FirebaseUI outside of `componentDidMount`, start it on `componentDidMount` and reset it on `componentWillUnmount`:

```
const authUi = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
class FirebaseUI extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    authUi.start('#firebaseui-auth', uiConfig);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    authUi.reset();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="firebaseui-auth"></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, so I did as you said but again the login component appears but not the firebaseUI logins (facebook, phone, etc)

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem for me. Basically `componentDidMount` does not after I rerender the component on logout (it's always there just hidden). So I need `componentDidUpdate` but that causes me to always show the login even after clicking 'login via facebook'